# typing 'emacs' on terminal stops terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal

Running `emacs` on terminal opens `emacs` on another GUI window on my Mac.
But the terminal won't accept any command until the `emacs` on GUI quits.

Any solution to let terminal answer for command even after booting `emacs`?

Thanks.

Comment: Do some reading about "job control" in a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run an interactive command (like emacs) on the terminal, it hangs until the command finishes. To avoid that, put the command on the background with an `&` at the end of the line:

```
emacs &
```

This way you start emacs on the background and release the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it works.